# Where are the multi-qubit openpulse computers?

Tags: ibm-q-experience, openpulse

As the question says, I'm looking to run some pulse schedules on quantum computers. Right now, I'm really only able to find ibmq_armonk (from IBM) to be an openpulse computer that I am able to use. I've found some papers that mentioned running pulse schedules on ibmq_toronto and ibmq_montreal, but IBMQ doesn't seem to identify them to support OpenPulse when applying the filters (though, this may just be because I'm on an unpaid account). Does anyone have any recommendations? I'm looking for both paid and unpaid services.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the backends with pulse support in the [table view of IBM service list](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services?services=systems&view=table), after signing in:

[image: openpulse systems]

Programmatically, you can list the backends with pulse support you have access to with Qiskit in the following way:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backends_supporting_openpulse = provider.backends(filters=lambda b: b.configuration().open_pulse)
```

You can add the `n_qubits >= 2` condition in the filter to add the multi-qubit part, like this:

```
provider.backends(filters=lambda b:
     b.configuration().open_pulse and 
     b.configuration().n_qubits >= 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use OpenPulse with Amazon Braket (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/braket/latest/developerguide/braket-hello-pulse-openpulse.html). This will allow you to run pulse schedules on Rigetti's Aspen-M quantum computer and Oxford Quantum Circuit's Lucy via AWS.